# How to check whether Hyper Threading is enabled or not in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hyperthreading

I am using the Ubuntu.
How can I check whether Hyper Threading is enabled or not.
And if it is disabled, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 7):

You can check the pseudo file [`/sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/active`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu) - it contains `1` if hyperthreading is enabled and `0` otherwise.

Shell example:

```
$ printf 'Hyperthreading '; \
      sed -e s/1/enabled/ -e s/0/disabled/ /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/active
```

You can either enable it in the BIOS - or in Linux with

```
# echo on > /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control
```

if and only if

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control
```

returns `off`.

Comment: I have a quad core cpu, and have 8 total threads, which is also what i see with `lscpu`. but i have read on internet that there should be 16 threads if i have hyperthreading enabled. your last command returned on for me. but, why am i only getting 8 threads then?

Comment: @NaveenKumar - most CPUs that implement hyperthreading implement 2 threads of execution per core. So 8 threads is expected for a quad core CPU then. You can also cross-check by looking up your CPU model name in the vendor's online CPU database.

Comment: I have a 1 in this file, but `dmidecode` shows 4 for both "Core Count" and "Thread Count".

Comment: @user2023370 dmidecode just reads out the DMI tables which are populated by the BIOS at some point during system initialization. Thus the information contained therein isn't necessarily accurate, especially after an operating system kernel (re-)initializes much hardware. If you want to get on the bottom of this you can cross check these numbers against the data sheet of your CPU and the `lscpu` output.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if HyperThreading is enable or not with

```
dmidecode -t processor|grep Count
```

if "Core Count" is the same as "Thread Count" ex:

Core Count: 32
Thread Count: 32

The HT is Disabled.

Else HT is Enabled.

Flag "HTT" shows the possibility of HyperThreading.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root permission

```
dmidecode -t processor | grep HTT
```

Comment: when i run grep -i 'ht' /proc/cpuinfo its showing flags in cpuinfo....what is the correct one

Comment: @AnilYadav I read your all comments in Leon's answers also, you have HT capability but it is not enabled. So you have to check in BIOS to find is it enabled or  not .

Comment: This only checks if the CPU supports hyperthreading, i.e. it also prints HTT if it's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can check cpuinfo

```
grep -i 'ht' /proc/cpuinfo
```

The ht flag indicates that Hyper Threading is enabled

Comment: its showing flags row....but when i run dmidecode -t processor | grep HTT command provide by Steephen its not showing anything.

Comment: I'm confused... Are you saying that the command above is not working?

Comment: oh, dmidecode requires sudo access... is it raising any errors?

Comment: In that case it could be that HyperThreading is disabled. On the command I gave, is the ht flag there? You can also run `dmidecode -t processor` without grep and check which flags are set

Comment: Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU socket #0
  Type: Central Processor
   Family: Unknown
  Manufacturer: GenuineIntel
   ID: D7 06 02 00 FF FB AB 1F
   Version:        Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz
   Voltage: 3.3 V
    External Clock: Unknown
     Max Speed: 30000 MHz
     Current Speed: 2700 MHz
     Status: Populated, Enabled
     Upgrade: ZIF Socket
     L1 Cache Handle: 0x0054
      L2 Cache Handle: 0x0055
 L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
  Serial Number: Not Specified
 Asset Tag: Not Specified
 Part Number: Not Specified
Handle 0x0042, DMI type 4, 35 bytes

Comment: Can you tell me how to Set it...?

Comment: Start by checking if it is enabled in the BIOS

Comment: This check just checks if the CPU supports hyperthreading. Since `/proc/cpuinfo` also contains the 'ht' flag if hyperthreading is disabled your grep always matches on CPUs with HT support - even if it's disabled.